# Can I use yum to install an additional apache httpd server?

Tags: apache, yum, centos7, mod-perl

I'm using a plain apache server as a front-end and a mod-perl enabled apache server as a backend with mod_proxy.

I'm in the process of moving to a new hosting company so I'm installing software. In the past I've built both of these from source but it would be easier to use yum to install so that they are easily updated.  Is it possible to install 2 separate httpd servers with yum? And if so how?

I'm thinking that the solution might be to move the front-end to lighttpd or similar but I'd still like to know whether it is possible.

I'm using Centos 7.

Comment: I've found these instructions 
http://linuxcrazyadmins.com/2015/04/19/setup-multiple-instances-of-apache-on-one-machine-centos/

The only problem is that they involve editing a startup file in /etc/init.d which does not exist in Centos 7.

Comment: According to this page - I just need a different configuration file for each instance - so it should be possible to run multiple instances using yum quite easily. I haven't got it to work yet though. The instructions are for FreeBSD rather than Centos.
https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RunningMultipleApacheInstances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem to have it working now. Hope this might help someone else.

I now have one httpd with two different configuration files in /etc/httpd/conf/: httpd_docs.conf and httpd_perl.conf

Set the PidFile to two different files at the top of the config files.

Copied the /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d to /etc/httpd/conf.modules.perl and updated the 'Include' in the two config files to point to the different directories and then deleted unnecessary files in each directory so that the httpd_docs instance does not use mod_perl and the httpd_perl instance does.

Copied /etc/sysconfig/httpd to /etc/sysconfig/httpd_perl and edited each one to include an OPTIONS line

```
OPTIONS="-d /etc/httpd -f conf/httpd_docs.conf"
```

and

```
OPTIONS="-d /etc/httpd -f conf/httpd_perl.conf"
```

Copied /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service to /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd_perl.service and edited to point to correct EnvironmentFile.

Used this question to help answer my own question
https://serverfault.com/questions/31838/can-rhel-4-have-two-instances-of-apache-httpd-running-using-two-different-config